# Is it any limitation for using the In-Role Cahce in Azure Cloud Service Application (PaaS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

Is it any limitation for using the In-Role Cahce in Azure Cloud Service Application (PaaS)?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh914161.aspx

Comment: Please share any specific concerns that you have with in role cache. As it stands now, the question is not clear.

Comment: In role cache will be deprecated by 11/30/2016 and so using redis cache service is the right option.

Comment: We had done some load test on the server. When the load is increased, then the application performance degraded and crashed the In-Role Service. Error is given below: [DataCacheException: ErrorCode<ERRCA0017>:SubStatus<ES0006>:There is a temporary failure. Please retry later. (One or more specified cache servers are unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers.